# Grimer in Arena let the game crash

Tags: pokemon-go

Today i was at a arena. A player from the red team put a Grimer there, which causes my game to crash every time I select the arena (Samsung Galaxy S4 mini). All other pokemons i saw so far did not make any problems

I searched a bit, and found out that this is a known bug, e.G.: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rzpjg/grimers_model_makes_my_game_crash/)

Now my question, is there a way to battle in the arena or even select it without crashing my app? Some option like "hide model in arena",changing some smartphone-settings or another trick? Or do i have to wait till a bugifx from niantec comes or somebody else which has a handy which dont crashes with grimer clears the arena, before selecting the arena? 
Because somebody could place him there i guess this is only a bug for specific smartphones, but this could be used to exclude a lot of players from arenafighting by only placing grimers in arenas to let the game crash for them, are there some official notes about this from niantec or how to avoid the crash?

Comment: There seems to be a solution now in that reddit thread you linked to - does that work?

Comment: @Tim Malone: I must admit, I dont play that game anymore and forgot my question here ;) . So I can not confirm or deny that solution. But I accepted Alfs answer, because it sounds like the last update fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a few users, cleaning data and cache seems to solve the problem, not for me, though... ([this is the source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4v6azy/found_a_possible_fix_for_grimer_bug_xpost_to/) for this).

There is also the small probability that submitting an official bug report might help, you can do so [here](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222061187).

**Update**: updating to version 0.37.0 seems to fix the Grimer bug for most devices.

Answer (score 1):

This seem to be pretty frequent bug affecting many mobile phone models. It  crases the Pokemon Go program whenever the Grimer's animation gets cached. This happens if you click on Grimer in the pokemon storage or in pokedex or if you click on adjacent pokemon in the storage or pokedex. Also it seems to happen if you go to gym where is Grimer or if you attempt to catch it. One of known workarounds that caches the animation correctly (and completely cure the bug until it is un-cached) is that you go to pokedex, go to ca 15th (existing) pokemon before Grimer, and then slide 15 times to right to Grimer. So you can theoretically do this before you approach the Gym and then you can beat the Gym normally. However you need to have Grimer in pokedex, so you must have it hatched.