# Hatched a Grimer - caused a crash with a lot of following crashes

Tags: pokemon-go

Hatched a Grimer which caused the game to crash during the hatch-animation. Clicking on Grimer afterwards, results in a freeze at the stats-screen of Grimer. It also results in freezes for every pokemon I caught after Grimer.

Crashed happened initially on the non-updated version. Tried a re-install (and now am updated to the latest version, i.e. 0.31.0) and still not working.

The phone I was playing on is a Sony Xperia Compact Z1.

Any ideas how to get rid of that bug ?

*Bug summary*: clicking on Grimer (either in the Pokédex or in the list with all your Pokémons) results in a freeze, so does clicking on the Pokémon left or right (before and behind), likely because the app is already trying to load the image of Grimer.

**Update 1**: I can click on any pokemon except on Grimer now without a crash <strike>but none of the images of any pokemon is loading. The images are only there when the pokemon stats are automatically showing up directly after you caught them.</strike> (see Update 3 for an explanation).

**Update 2**: Android Version 4.4.4

**Update 3**: After a few crashes and restarts, the pokemon images are back.

**Update 4**: After a little bit of research, I found that for [a few users, cleaning the data and the cache might help](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4v6azy/found_a_possible_fix_for_grimer_bug_xpost_to/) (did not work for me and for most of the other users.). Also, I [submitted an official bug report](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222061187), just to let them know (they might read it, maybe...).

**Update 5**: Bug is still there in current version (0.33.0)

**Update 6**: Version 0.35.0, bug is still there

**Update 7** (as requested from @Vemonus): in my opinion, it is not a duplicate of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276998/grimer-in-arena-let-the-game-crash) since that question was specifically addressing the arenas (when somebody else put a Grimer there) whereas here we are talking about the situation when *you* own a Grimer (although the origin of the bug is, of course, the same: Grimer's heavy animation).

Comment: Any ideas how to get rid of that bug ? You didn't talk about any Weedle/Caterpie...kinda lost :P

Comment: @MarioGarcia well, caught indeed a few Weedles/Caterpies afterwards, clicking on them caused a freeze. I had to fully re-install the game. Now, I can at least click on them without causing a freeze. **But**: the images of the pokemons are not loading ...

Comment: was a joke, about weedle and caterpie being bugs, but not grimer. I think I had a friend with a similar glitch, will try to ask him later and come back with some feedback

Comment: @MarioGarcia ahem.... sorry for forcing you to explain that joke, should have realized it :D

Comment: post ur android version, just in case

Comment: @MarioGarcia ups, totally forgotten that (added now)

Comment: @Vemonus I added an update to the question concerning the possible  duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the Grimer bug, you need to update to version 0.37.0 (at least this worked in my case and I saw a few more positive reports on reddit).

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug that your game will crash when clicking Grimer on some phones, as long as you don't click it you should be good.

Comment: Got a source for this? It seems like an awfully specific bug.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4u53yy/grimer_bug_investigation/ https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4tw56c/game_crashes_because_of_grimer/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rzpjg/grimers_model_makes_my_game_crash/

Although it doesn't seem that it's specific to Android 4.4 like I initially thought

Comment: Heh, with that bug out there, makes me want to put a Grimer in all the Gyms near me so anyone with older Android versions can't capture them :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I actually read somewhere somebody complaining he can't take a gym due to the fact that a Grimer was put there...

Comment: @Riley the bug was definitely also there for the previous version

Comment: @Alf it was? Odd they left it in there..

Comment: @alf:that was a question from me,my Phone crashes because of grimer and had the issue once that he was in an arena. But got no answer, it seems there is nothing i can do about it.but after restarting the app i had no additional trouble like you

Comment: @kl78 ah, indeed, this is [your post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276998/grimer-in-arena-let-the-game-crash).